# If I am using SQL Server 2012 and EF6 is there any advantage to adding a Generic Repository into the mix?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-mapping

I am using SQL Server 2012 with Entity Framework, a Generic Repository and a service layer. It's my intention to always use EF and SQL Server.

This is working fine but it was suggested to me that I do not really need a generic repositories on top of EF's built-in repositories.

Can someone out there tell me if there is any advantage to using a generic repository? I'm not looking for opinions on one or the other as experience in the 
past tells me as soon as the word opinion is mentioned the question gets closed by people :-(

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting is also known in the ORM world as a second-level cache. While it can greatly improve performance, it is pretty difficult to implement correctly. Here's a couple resources that explore the pros and cons, and discuss implementation details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx
http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1394141

Answer (score 1):

Adding data patterns to your data layer such as generic repository pattern provides a level of abstraction which in turn has advantages such as making your code testable.

On a side note, another data pattern that you might want to consider coupling with GR is the Unit of Work pattern. This will allow you to group transactions and perform logical operations such as committing and rollingback changes.

I personally don't see any performance gains on using such patterns but it certainly makes development easier and make the code easier to maintain which I think is a plus.

[Link to Unit of Work Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Repository pattern is for persisting and retrieving Aggregates of your domain(aggregate is something that includes entities and Value objects(DDDesign)). entity framework supports for UnitOfWork pattern by default(context.SaveChanges()) and you still need for repository patterns to retrieve and persist your aggregates and entities.
most of the peoples use UnitofWork and also handle the CRUD operations in Data access layer, but as I mentioned now entity framework supports for unitofwork and you can use only repository pattern only in your repository later.

see this blog posts, hope it helps:

http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/44/does-it-cause-any-kind-of-performance-issue-using-a-base-class-in-layer-supertype-pattern

http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/8/repository-pattern-practice-in-data-access-layer-via-entity-framework

http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/23/layer-supertype-pattern-with-example-in-c